# 11 days from now

Tags: javascript, date

I know there are a few similar posts about this topic, but none were helping me much (or maybe that's cause I'm still a newbie).

Anyway, the thing I'm looking for is a script to show me the day and date + 11 days from now.

The script below is what I use to show the current day & date. So I figured there has to be some simple line to add or modify somewhere? like "+11"

Any helpful answer would be very very very much appreciated!

---

```
var daynames = new Array( "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

var months = new Array( "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december");

var currentTime = new Date();

var dayname = currentTime.getDay();

var month = currentTime.getMonth();

var day = currentTime.getDate();

var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

document.write(daynames[dayname] + "<BR> " + day  + " " + months[month]  + " " + year);
```

Comment: Instead of parroting your title in the tags, more useful tags would have been the language and platform you are using.

Comment: I second Oded, what is your language and platform ? I'd guess Javascript based on the code, but there is no way of really telling :-)

Comment: At least there's no "11" tag.

Comment: I've fixed the tags. If this isn't JavaScript, please fix them again.

Comment: And please "accept" an answer, thats how stackoverflow works. Also, you must have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working on JavaScript, this snippet will set d to +11 days from current day -

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming javascript because of `document.write`

```
var yourDate=new Date();
yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate()+11); //11 is the number of days you want to add
```

Refer: [getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as from cyclotrojan : -1

Comment: @ThorstenS.: It's not *exactly* the same, and it was posted 2 minutes after cyclotrojan's answer. He likely didn't see the other answer before posting. This doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Yup, didn't see his answer. Was searching for MDN links to cite.

Comment: @Both: Both answers are beginning with "Assuming [...] javascript" and they are using the *exact* same code with different variable names (e.g. using instead temporary vars to add the date). I hope that my suspicion is understandable. After looking up some answers and seeing that nunespascal does not copy answers, I retract my downvote. Sorry.